# Volume of revolution of solid formed by $y=-2x^2+3x$ and $y=x^a$ about $y$-axis where $a$ is a constant > 1

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to find an expression with constant $a$ for the volume of the solid in the first quadrant between $y=-2x^2+3x$ and $y=x^a$ rotated around the $y$-axis. I attempted this problem using the washer method but it seemed overly complicated and long and am wondering if there is a more simple method. I first completed the square for $y=-2x^2+3x$ to rewrote it to $$x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{9-8y}}4$$ and I wrote $y=x^a$ as $x=y^{1/a}$
I then used the washer method from $y=0$ to $y=1$ and added a second integral from $y=1$ to $y=1.125$ (maximum of $y=-2x^2+3x$) using the washer method with the rewritten equation (the big one above) using both the $+$ and $-$ for the 2 equations. Again, this method seemed pretty complicated to me and I'm still not sure as to the correct answer so I wanted to know if there is another simpler way to do this problem. The answer does not need to be integrated, you can write the definite integral without computing it.

[Here is a graph with a=2 as example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjH3P.png)

Comment: @spencer It's being rotated around the y-axis. I wasn't clear enough but I edited by post to clarify

Comment: This question (as posed, and as linked) has nothing whatsoever to do with a *volume*.  Right?

Answer (score 1):

You say "volume of the solid," but the equations and the picture define a 2-dimensional figure not a solid.  Are you rotating this about the x- or y-axis?  Or are you really looking for the area between the curves?